# FullCalender v5.0 not supporting viewRender for React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to call a function via `viewRender` prop in React FullCalender implementation. But it is not calling on click of next month or prev month. Did anyone face this issue ? `viewDidMount` works well when I change the view from say, month to week or visa versa.

Comment: viewRender doesn't exist in fullcalendar v5. It's nothing to do with React, it just simply isn't an option in the core library anymore. In fact it hasn't existed since v3. All the current options are listed here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc .

Comment: But anyway you mentioned that you wanted this so you could detect click of next month or prev month. My question would be, why do you need to detect that? In my experience whenever someone asks for this requirement (which happens reasonably often) there is almost always a better way to achieve their goal. So please explain your overall reason for wanting to detect these clicks and maybe we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: When I click on nextMonth or previousMonth, new calender dates are rendered in the table of DOM. I need to add some class to the new dates as soon as they are rendered.

Comment: Have you tried any of the various sets of hooks listed under https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-display ? These seem to deal with the rendering of individual days and times

Comment: Yes I am trying that now. It is not perfect choice for me but seems to be doing its job. I wanted something that only calls once after click of next and prev buttons. But these hooks calls as many times as there are dates.

Comment: That's in case you want to do something different depending on the exact date. But does it really matter? It gets the job done.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have some event call on calendar view change you can try to use [datesSet](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet) event. In the returned object you will get a view name field.

[image]